# Force login a user as a locally generated user when using OAuth2 strategy in PassportJS?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Is it possible to force login a user as a locally generated user when using OAuth2 strategy in PassportJS? I need to force login of a specific user for the purposes of developing on local. Maybe by manually generating the auth cookie or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the login method is used for this. In a route handler, put something like this:

```
    if req.headers.host == 'localhost'
        user = {id: 109593029532252360621}
        req.login user, (err) ->
            if !err
                return res.redirect('/')
```